# Chrome Bookmark Folder in google sheet by google App Scripts

Tags: google-chrome, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I need to import all url of a specific folder of my chrome bookmarks in a google sheet . Url 1 in A1 , Url 2 in A2 etc.... 
I have to do it in Google Apps script

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I am sorry, I don't understand your question.I don't find any solution so this is the reason of my question

Comment: I know to read a folder of google drive because of "driveApp" but i don't know how to put a chrome/bookmark folder  in a google drive folder

Comment: Sorry Michel, justed wanted to ask, if you have written some code, to post it so that others are able to help you out more easily...

Comment: I'm guessing you need a chrome-addon to access the bookmarks first and then apps script to a sheet. Or You can manually export them  and store  it in drive and then access/parse them

Comment: this is for all wikipedia contributors. . theses contributors already do this  manually export  thousand times by day . this is the reason of automation. 
Ok for your plan B "Chrome add on" . Unfortunalty i don't know this langage. . so I still need help  
https://developer.chrome.com/extensions

Comment: @Michel196 Sorry but SO is a specific Q/A site for programming related questions only. Try searching for addons on the  Chrome store(If you're lucky, you'll find one easily) or try asking for help on forums.